# Add meld in the contextual menu

Tags: debian, nautilus, meld

Is it possible to add Meld in the contextual menu to easily compare 2 files ?
On Windows, I can do that with Beyond Compare, would it be possible to do the same in Nautilus ?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

https://launchpad.net/nautilus-compare/

nautilus-compare is an extension for naulitus that uses meld for diff comparisons.

Comment: For Debian users: `nautilus-compare` [was removed](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=954962) from the repositories because it's based on python2.
A new release based on python3 is available but misses [someone to package it for Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=942772).

Comment: it's incredibly easy to manually install for someone who wants it... one could use the Arch AUR package for reference; https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=nautilus-compare ... it's literally moving a handful of files into their correct paths

Answer (score 0):

The deb package from [1](https://launchpad.net/%7Eboamaod/+archive/ubuntu/nautilus-compare/+files/nautilus-compare_1.0.0%7Efocal1_all.deb) used to work with previous versions of nautilus on Debian:

Now for Gnome 43 and above, it is necessary to replace the line

```
    def get_file_items(self, window, files):
```

with

```
    def get_file_items(self, files):
```

in file nautilus-compare.py, for this extremely useful nautilus extension to work.

[image: Screenshot of nautilus-compare in Gnome 43]

Comment: It doesn't work on my Debian 11 and Cinnamon 4.8.6